# Total the aggregate in Select Case Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a way to get a total from the aggregate in each select case statement? The following gives me the correct total by listing the total for each month in a column but I would like to have a single total for each case statement.

```
SELECT SUM(
           CASE WHEN dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2016-12-31' THEN dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.Amount ELSE 0 END
           ) AS 'Dec16'
        , SUM(
              CASE WHEN dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2017-01-31' THEN dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.Amount ELSE 0 END
              ) AS 'JAN17'
FROM dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction
INNER JOIN dbo.bill_t_TripTicket ON (
                                     dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.RunNumber = dbo.bill_t_TripTicket.RunNumber
                                     )
INNER JOIN dbo.med_m_Company     ON (
                                     dbo.bill_t_TripTicket.CompanyCode = dbo.med_m_Company.CompanyCode
                                     )
WHERE dbo.bill_t_TripTicket.CompanyCode = '105'
  AND dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
GROUP BY dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.TransactionDate
```

Comment: So you want to group by Dec16 and Jan17?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the format that you wnat hte results in.

Comment: Correct - I would like a single total for Dec16 then a total for Jan17.  Each month as the fiscal year progresses I would like for the next column to include everything prior and add the current month to the total.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I did not see I had choices in my tag.

Comment: So you want the month and a running total for Dec16 and Jan17?

Answer (score 0):

I just formated your SQL - so it will be more readable for human beings - and put it in a Subselect. 
In the outer Select i just added the SUM of the two calculated columns

```
SELECT sums.*
      ,SUM(sums.DEC16 + sums.JAN17) AS TOTAL_SUM
  FROM (     
            SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.TransactionDate 
                                  BETWEEN '2000-01-01' 
                                      AND '2016-12-31' 
                             THEN dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.Amount 
                             ELSE 0 
                        END
                       ) AS DEC16
                   ,SUM( CASE WHEN dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.TransactionDate 
                                   BETWEEN '2000-01-01' 
                                       AND '2017-01-31' 
                              THEN dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.Amount 
                              ELSE 0 
                         END
                       ) AS JAN17
             FROM dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction
            INNER JOIN dbo.bill_t_TripTicket 
               ON dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.RunNumber = dbo.bill_t_TripTicket.RunNumber
            INNER JOIN dbo.med_m_Company     
               ON dbo.bill_t_TripTicket.CompanyCode  = dbo.med_m_Company.CompanyCode
            WHERE dbo.bill_t_TripTicket.CompanyCode        = '105'
              AND dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
            GROUP BY dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.TransactionDate
        ) sums
```

Comment: I apologize. I guess I wasn't clear enough. Esteban your query does total each month (after I added a group by clause for the sums aggregate). Each row is Dec + Jan for each month in the date range. I would like to have a single sum. Dec16 would be the sum of 2000-01-01 to 2016-12-31 then Jan17 would be the sum of 2000-01-01 to 2017-01-31.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, Transaction.TransactionDate) + RIGHT(YEAR(Transaction.TransactionDate), 2) AS MonthYear
,       SUM(Transaction.Amount) AS Amount
FROM    dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction Transaction
INNER JOIN dbo.bill_t_TripTicket Ticket
    ON Transaction.RunNumber = Ticket.RunNumber 
INNER JOIN dbo.med_m_Company Company
    ON Ticket.CompanyCode = Company.CompanyCode 
WHERE   Ticket.CompanyCode = '105'
        AND Transaction.TransactionDate >= '2000-01-01' 
        AND Transaction.TransactionDate < '2017-02-01'
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, Transaction.TransactionDate) + RIGHT(YEAR(Transaction.TransactionDate), 2)
```

Assuming `dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.TransactionDate` is a `datetime(2)`: Are you aware that in 'DEC16' you are missing transaction from (as an example) `2016-12-31 11:00:00`? `BETWEEN` is inclusive on both sides, and dates are defaulted to midnight (00:00:00) if no time component is defined. I altered the `WHERE` clause accordingly. I also added aliases to help the readability.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to get right of the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ba.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
               THEN ba.Amount ELSE 0
           END) AS Dec16,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ba.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
                THEN ba.Amount ELSE 0
            END) AS JAN17
FROM dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction ba INNER JOIN
     dbo.bill_t_TripTicket bt
     ON ba.RunNumber = bt.RunNumber INNER JOIN
     dbo.med_m_Company c
     ON bt.CompanyCode = c.CompanyCode
WHERE bt.CompanyCode = '105' AND
      ba.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2017-01-31';
```

Note the other changes I made to the query:

- I removed the single quotes from the column aliases.  Single quotes should only be used for string and date values (using them for column aliases is allowed but can cause confusion).
- The tables are given aliases.
- The column names are qualified with the aliases (the query is easier to write and to read.
- Note that `'105'` should not have quotes, if `CompanyCode` is numeric.

I think the query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ba.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
               THEN ba.Amount ELSE 0
           END) AS Dec16,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ba.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
                THEN ba.Amount ELSE 0
            END) AS JAN17
FROM dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction ba INNER JOIN
     dbo.bill_t_TripTicket bt
     ON ba.RunNumber = bt.RunNumber 
WHERE bt.CompanyCode = 105 AND
      ba.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2017-01-31';
```

The `Company` table does not appear to be being used.

Comment: SOLVED - Thank you Gordon - The top is exactly what I was trying to do. Also please a great thank to you all that helped. This group is fantasitc!